# How do you replicate a Dbase database to MYSQL in real time?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-foxpro, dbase

I have a massive dBase DB (Visual FoxPro vfp). I need to replicate it to a Mysql DB in real time.

To help, I made a c# service to dump the entire information from specific tables from dBase to Mysql by doing a full delete in each Mysql table and then insert everything back again from each dBase DB table. However, this can hardly be called replication and it's performs extremely poorly for larger dBase tables.

I am unable to modify the program using the VFP file directly. I can only access the database files themselves.

How can I achieve said task in an efficient way, in real or near real time?

Comment: There are several ways, but you _must_ do some setup -- The main ways to copy _from_ MySQL involve:  Replication; LVM; cloud services.  If you have not prepped for any of those, you are probably out of luck.  (I don't know about dBase.)

Comment: One way replication in real time could be done by modifying the FoxPro database container files (*.dbc/.dct) by adding Delete/Insert/Update Triggers there without "modifying the program" i.e. the vfp.EXE file. See also https://www.cdata.com/drivers/xbase/

Comment: @RickJames from MySQL i could find a lot of information, is just dBase that's super dark stuff.

Comment: @StefanWuebbe As far as I've read vfp does not have triggers for their db haha and cdata looks amazing but seing how they don't even include pricing in their site I'm very inclined to think it's not cheap and i to invest sync'ing a very old type of db it'd be cheaper to just get a new software with newer technologies altogether haha

Comment: I have put a few Links into an Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually VFP *.DBC Database Containers do support Triggers. In the Vfp IDE you can use the `Modify Database` command and then act interactively in the Database Designer or

```
 CREATE TRIGGER ON myTable FOR DELETE|INSERT|UPDATE AS myTrigger()
```

in the Command Window.
See also [create a trigger for update, delete or insert in FoxPro Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090805/create-a-trigger-for-update-delete-or-insert-in-foxpro-table)
and [Create FoxPro Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956631/create-foxpro-trigger?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Edit]
Inside the Triggers' `Stored Procedure` code you can use FoxPro SQL Pass-Through SPT code namely VfP's SQL*() functions like `SQL(String)Connect()`, `SQLExec()` or `Remote Views` or `CursorAdapters` that would send (parametrized) SQL statements to your MySQL server.

Example:

```
LOCAL lcConnString
IF m.llSuccess
    lcConnString = ;
        [DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver;] + ;
        [USER=] + m.lcUser + [;] + ;
        [PASSWORD=] + m.lcPwd + [;] + ;
        [DATABASE=Test;] + ;
        [SERVER=] + m.lcServer+ [;] + ;
        [OPTION=3;]
ENDIF

PUBLIC h
IF m.llSuccess
    h = SQLSTRINGCONNECT(m.lcConnstring)
    llSuccess = ( h > 0 )
    lcErrorMessage = "Connection failed."
ENDIF

Local lnPk, lnValue, lcSQL, lnSuccess, laSQLErrors[1]
IF m.llSuccess
    lnPk = 15887
    lnValue = 15
    lcSQL = "Insert Into test (primaryKey, testInt) Values (?m.lnPk, ?m.lnValue)"
    lnSuccess = SqlExec(h,m.lcSQL)
    llSuccess = ( m.lnSuccess > 0 )

    IF m.lnSuccess < 1
        AERROR(laSQLErrors)
        lcErrorMessage = ;
            TRANSFORM(laSQLErrors[1]) + ", " + ;
            TRANSFORM(laSQLErrors[2])
    ENDIF
ENDIF

IF h > 0
    SQLDISCONNECT(h)
ENDIF
```

As for the commercial CData 3rd party tool, they offer an xBase/ dBase driver
https://www.cdata.com/drivers/xbase/
as well as a "Universal Data Pipeline" Replication tool that I have not tried myself yet:
https://www.cdata.com/sync/ ,
https://www.cdata.com/sync/#purchase

Comment: oohhh, i see! the cdata solution is way out of budget for our goal, sadly. 

Adding triggers to the dbc i could only modify the dbf tables themselves :(

Comment: I have added a VFP-MySQL-connection code example

Comment: Accepting it as the answer as you even included code to connect to MySQL. Thank you!

Comment: @Hikaros, you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, I've made something like this using the following approach: I created triggers to log to a table the ID of the records manipulated. Then I set a periodic routine to run every few minutes, reading the log e sending the actual records values to a Postgres destination database in the cloud.

First, check if the tables in DBC have some way to identify each record uniquely, you can try to create triggers on these tables, capturing every time they have been changed (adding, updating, or deleting records) and logging the identification of that record (probably the value of the table's primary key) to a LOG table. This log table could be like this:

SYNC_LOG.DBF fields:
table (Char)
key (Char or Int or what else the system uses)
action (Char) "Insert" or "Update" or "Delete"
Processed Boolean (false or true)

So, every time a record in the same table is inserted, updated, or deleted, the triggers log the action to SYNC_LOG.DBF setting the "processed" field to FALSE.

If a log for that record already exists and it is NOT processed yet, the trigger doesn't need to create a new log. Defining this rule guarantees the log file won't get bigger indefinitely.

This is the first part. The second is to create a routine that will check de log file periodically and send commands to update the de-destination database.

All these can be done easily 100% in VFP, but I don't know your knowledge with the fox.

Comment: My knowledge of vfp is extremely poor, however, I can get help with that, i will talk about this with that person. Thank you :)